# Ciclo For Condición con Contador

Tags: javascript

Hola buen día quiero si me pueden apoyar con una lógica tengo 11814 registros que recorro con un for, cada vez que se va recorriendo el for se va guardando datos en la variable qry, pero quiero que por cada 100 registros recorridos se ejecute el código `ejecuta.query("IXMLS",qry); qry.exec();` como llegara un momentos de no tenga los 100 registros me haga la ejecución con el resto, quiero nada mas un ejemplo no importa el lenguaje solo quiero una idea de como hacerlo.

```
funcion procesa(){              
    var totalReg=11814;
    var aux=0;
    for (var i=0;i<totalReg;i++){                   
        if(frn.get("id",i,"sn")&="Si"){
            var serie=frn.get("tabla2",i,"serie");

    var qry=qry&"

    MERGE KDFEXMLEMI AS XMLS 
    USING (SELECT '"&serie&"') AS XMLSBUS (campo)   
    ON XMLS.C1=XMLSBUS.C1
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET XMLS.Campo=XMLSBUS.campo
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(campo,) VALUES (XMLSBUS.campo);                                
                ";

                if(aux&="100" && totalReg>"100"){
                    ejecuta.query("IXMLS",qry);
                    qry.exec();
                    qry="";
                    totalReg=totalReg-aux;
                    aux=0;  
                }else if(totalReg<"100" && aux<"100"){
                    //frn.message(totalReg&"+++"&totalReg&"++++"&aux);
                    kdb.query("datIXMLS",qry);
                    kdb.exec();
                    qry="";
                    totalReg=totalReg-aux;
                    aux=0;  
                }
                aux++;                      
            }                                                                                                           
        }

        if(totalReg&="0"){                                  
            message("Registros Procesados");    

        }

    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías replicar tu error en el simulador que tiene la plataforma? También, sería de ayuda que pongas qué te retorna y qué te gustaría obtener con un ejemplo real.

Comment: no me queda claro si es cada 100 registros o fracción, es decir la última vez es a los 11800 u 11814?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradecería que nos brindes un poco mas de información sobre que es la salida que esperas. Por lo que veo quieres disparar una función cada que recorras 100 registros. El arreglo lo recorres con:

```
for (var i=0;i<totalReg;i++){...}
```

Entonces algo fácil que puedes hacer es indicarle a tu bucle que dispare una función cada múltiplo de 100 o sea, si `k = i+1`cada que `(k %= 100) === 0`.Por ejemplo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 103; i++) {
  let k = i+1;

  if((k %= 100) === 0){
    console.log(`Registro num: ${i+1} - Cada 100 iteraciones se ejecuta esto`);
  }
  else {
    console.log(`Registro num: ${i+1} - No es multiplo de 100`);
  }
}
```

Esto dispara una acción cada 100 iteraciones.

Te dejo un ejemplo (disparando cada 10 iteraciones) para que lo ejecutes

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 103; i++) {
  let k = i+1;

  if((k %= 10) === 0){
    console.log(`Registro num: ${i+1} - Cada 10 iteraciones se ejecuta esto`);
  }
  else {
    console.log(`Registro num: ${i+1} - No es multiplo de 10`);
  }
}
```

Comment: gracias @Edher Carbajal me sirvio bastante me pude dar una idea en mi codigo